# Including a variable local macro inside a loop

Tags: for-loop, stata, local, stata-macros

Using a `forvalues` loop, I am merging a list of 400 individual datasets.

These datasets can be one of 10 distinct values (defined by a variable in the dataset): depending on the dataset, I would `merge` with a different dataset. For example, if Player 90 was type 9, I would want to merge with `Type_9.dta` rather than `Type_8` or `Type_7`.

What I want is something like this:

```
forvalues x = 1/400 {
    use "player_`x'.dta"

    * some way to turn the value of player type into a local macro l *

    merge 1:1 using "type_`l'.dta"
}
```

How can i get the variable type into a macro that changes for each type through the loop?

Comment: Did the answer below help?

Answer (score 1):

The structure of your data and the ultimate goal are not quite clear to me, so there may be more efficient ways to do that.

If player_type does not vary within each player_* data set, you can use `levelsof`. This has the feature that if player_type varies for some reason like a data entry error, the loop will error out.

```
forvalues x = 1/400 { 
   use "player_`x'.dta"
   levelsof player_type, local(l)
   merge 1:1 **some_id_var** using "type_`l'.dta" 
}
```

Comment: This isn't clear to me either: for example, if you have already `merge`d one dataset, what is to stop that being done again? But if `player_type` is constant, it will suffice to use the value of `player_type[1]`, so no need to fire up `levelsof`.

Comment: I used `levelsof` because the loop will break if `player_type` is not in fact constant.

Comment: Fine; I see that now. Better to spell that out in a revision of your answer?